# While loop gets stuck when using == or !=

Tags: c, button, raspberry-pi

I am programming the gpio pins on my rapsberry pi in C. No I get stuck in a while loop. When I use == or != it doesn't matter, the loop gets stuck. Is this because when the program goes in the loop it doesn't update the state of the variables in that the while loop uses?

```
for(i=0;i<200;i++)
{
    uint8_t valu = bcm2835_gpio_lev(SIG);
    while(valu == 0)
        {
        uint8_t valu = bcm2835_gpio_lev(SIG);
        data[i] = 0;
        dan = dan + 1;
        delay(0.001);
        }

    timeout = 0;

    while(val == 1 && timeout < 70)
        {
        uint8_t val = bcm2835_gpio_lev(SIG);
        data[i] = data[i] + 1;
        dat = dat + 1;
        timeout = timeout + 1;
        delay(0.001);
        }

delay(0.001);
}
```

the bcm2835 instructions are from the c library for the broadcom IC the raspberry pi uses.

Comment: @staticx Although the question you link to is about the same GPIO's, what this user needs is a basic tutorial in C; the question is more about about scope of variables than about GPIO pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
uint8_t valu = bcm2835_gpio_lev(SIG);
uint8_t val = 1;
while(valu == 0)
    {
    valu = bcm2835_gpio_lev(SIG);
    data[i] = 0;
    dan = dan + 1;
    delay(0.001);
    }
```

...

```
while(val == 1 && timeout < 70)
    {
    val = bcm2835_gpio_lev(SIG);
    data[i] = data[i] + 1;
    dat = dat + 1;
    timeout = timeout + 1;
    delay(0.001);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Neither loop modifies val/valu, because it defines a NEW variable w/ the same name in that loop, effectively hiding the one used in the loop guard.